# Why does my armature deform incorrectly?

Tags: armature

I have been trying to create a rig for my model of a dragon (it is a school project). I have restraints on the eye, inverse kinematics on the legs, and a spline restriction on the tail. I stupidly made the teeth as a separate object, sculpted the mouth to include the teeth, and then used ctr+j to make it a part of the dragon. Before using ctr+j, the teeth moved very weirdly but everything else worked. After joining the teeth everything went weird. How do I make this armature work?[the images show what happens when I parent the armature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kwGc.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you've selected the teeth, then the body, then ctrl J, it should work, you just have to weight paint the teeth so that they follow their bone. Perhaps share your file to see how to fix your problem? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I connected the teeth in the way you said, but when I parent my armature, the sculpt for the gums disappears. I tried to google why this happens but can not find anything. Where should I post the file? Create a new post?

Comment: I went to the link you sent but my file is 30.68MiB and it says the maximum to upload is 30...  @moonboots

Comment: Sorry I am new to this and do not know how to notify you when I comment @moonboots . I hope this works

Comment: so perhaps use another site like wetransfer to share your file

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to your problem, it is basic rigging problem, you should follow tutorials on this topic:

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful! I am however still struggling here. It looks like you joined the teeth and main geometry together. When I do that, I lose my sculpt mode edit (it looks like you did too). Also, if I do not join them to prevent the multires modifier from messing up, the model moves up when I parent so the bones are not in the right place anymore. Am I just missing something obvious? @moonboots

Comment: Actually the teeth were already joined to the rest of the body, and I just deactivated the Multires to ease my test, I tried to solve the teeth problem but I guess there are others. but It becomes a bit confusing to me, if rigging is not clear to you perhaps you should follow some more basic tutorials about this topic.

Comment: oh. Perhaps I gave you a file that had them joined and already messed up. Anyway, I have followed some basic tutorials (mostly by CGguru you YT) and understand it for the most part. I just do not understand how to keep a modifier after joining objects. @moonboots

Comment: when you join two object with ctrl J, the first object you select will lose its modifiers, so the modifiers of the second object will apply to the first, is it what you want to know?

Comment: I actually figured that out just by playing with it. But even if I keep it, it messes up. The modifier remains, but if I hide it with the eye button (dunno its oficial name) then bring it right back, the mesh smooths over, but the sculpt is gone. I can add more screenshots if you want. PS. the selection of teeth and using vertex groups is a great help :)  @moonboots

Comment: Oh yes it looks like if you join an object with another one that has Multires, the multires sculpt is lost, I didn't know that, so I guess you need to take that into account, maybe use dyntopo instead?

Comment: I will look into dyntopo. I have never tried or even heard about it so I will have to experiment. Thanks! @moonboots

Comment: It's an easy way to add details to your topology, but at the end it will be better to bake the result to lighten the mesh, so keep a low version, this topic talks about the difference between dyntopo and multires: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116868/sculpting-everything-is-edgy-and-sharp-but-i-want-it-smooth/116869?noredirect=1#comment204729_116869

Comment: I actually figured out how to make it work without even joining the teeth to the main mesh. I just had to do a quick re-sculpt and it was all good. I now have questions about keeping the eye in its socket when I move the top jaw as well as keeping the splike restraints handles connected to the spline restraint when I move the entire mesh. I think I will just make a new post for that because it is a new topic. Thank you sm for teh help @moonboots