# Problem with linking Objects to Bone

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

So I tried weight painting first then just simply straight "Assigning" bones but either method results in the below picture.
[image]

As you can see, when I move the model in pose mode the face objects attached to the head bone clip through the body mesh. Any help would be very much appreciated.

PS. I also don't know how to have the bones show up in the "vertex groups" for the "Pupils" object. Somehow they show in the other face objects but not the pupils. Help with that would also be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I've just answered to this kind of question here, I hop it will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127286/why-does-my-armature-deform-incorrectly?noredirect=1#comment220745_127286

Comment: @moonboots

I did as shown on the link you gave me, but now when I try to parent the objects to a bone, nothing happens. I tried weight painting too and it already says those objects are painted red so they should move, but they don't.

Comment: when you weight paint, make sure that your armature is in Pose mode, and select the bone you need to see what is its influence. But perhaps share your file so that we can see what's your problem: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5685" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5685/)

That's the file. Hope you can solve this cause I've been trying for months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you should lower down the *Subsurf* View value of all your objects to 2 because at 5 it's hard to work.

Now, about your problem, it's because your eyes, eyebrows and eyelids are separate objects, and you didn't parent them *With Automatic Weight* but directly to armature as a simple parent: as you can see, if you select them, enter in *Edit* mode, and see what are their vertex groups in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Vertex Groups*, there's only Armature (meaning the armature object on its whole will move these objects, but not the bones within this armature, i.e. like a basic parentage from an object to another).

So first select eyes, eyebrows and eyelids, join them to the whole body with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, go back in the vertex groups list of the whole body and delete this Armature group. Now assign all these new vertices to the group called "head". It should work (well, still some corrections to make in *Weight Paint* mode so that the neck bone doesn't affect the head mesh).

Hurray and Happy New Year !!!!