# How do I make a model high poly?

Tags: sculpting

I'm making a character and before retopologizing, many tutorials say to make it high resolution and polish it. But how?

Is it done with 'remesh'? If yes what number should I set it to?

Or is it done with dynamic topology 'flood fill'?

Or is there a different method? Thank you!

Edit:
[image]

[image]

First pic is the full mesh without subdivision surface, second pic is a close-up of the face with subdivision level 1 added. If I try to sculpt on the face it's super slow and I basically can't see what I'm doing.
My question is how to get it smooth and polished so I could retopologize it.

Comment: I think there are 2 main methods to sculpt in high-poly: Dyntopo or Multires. Someone presents the pros and cons of the 2 methods here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116868/sculpting-everything-is-edgy-and-sharp-but-i-want-it-smooth/116869?noredirect=1#comment204729_116869

Comment: So if i would subdivide my model it'd make it more polished and smooth? I really just want to make my character from not completely smooth (you can still see some faces and stuff) to very smooth. Does subdivide do that?

Comment: oh I thought you wanted to sculpt it as you were talking about Dyntopo... If you want to make it smooth you can give it a Subdivision Surface modifier, and also right click > Shade Smooth. You can keep this modifier, you don't have to apply it unless you need to export into a game engine for example. It's a way to make an object smoother without adding geometry for real

Comment: Ohh and could I keep sculpting and refining and then retopologize it (if I do apply it)?

Comment: yes, but always keep a low-poly version of your object

Comment: I applied only 1 subdivision but it's so so slow now, I can't even see where i'm sculpting. Is my Laptop the problem and I can't do this type of thing with my current setup? :( (I didn't even fully apply it)

Comment: it's possible. You say you "didn't fully apply it", but it doesn't mean anything, a modifier is either applied or not applied  ;)  maybe check a tutorial about the Subdivision Surface modifier, when and how to use it

Comment: Well I didn't click apply but it still subdivided, that's what I meant. :/

Comment: it really depends on your mesh, please show some screenshots

Comment: I did! Hope it helps :)

Comment: it seems high-poly enough, retopology is to make a low-poly from a high-poly, it would bring nothing to make it higher in polygon, you could even delete some polygons if it's too high for your computer (always keep copies of your object so that you can come back if you ever need)

Comment: If I repologize it and then add subdivide to the retopologized version will it look smooth? Also, the tutorial I'm talking about is this: https://youtu.be/f-mx-Jfx9lA at about 5:55min he talks about having it high res and polishing it, that's where my question came from.

Comment: exactly, you can smooth a low-poly mesh with the Subdivision Surface modifier and right click > Shade Smooth. You can also bake the normals of the high-poly if you ever want to add details to your low-poly, normals will fake 3D without additional topology. Not sure what he's referring to when he speaks about polishing, don't add useless geometry, it will slow down your computer, unless you need high quality details for example to have a nice bake (watch some tutorials about baking the normals)